# Array Formula not auto-filling in Google Sheets? [Example Provided]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that will not auto fill my array formula. Can someone please explain what I might be doing wrong on this? [Example Spreadsheet (Editable)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kkXOkYje62uMfyd1NGx7NiabwwfDAbTUaEfIV42gPOY/edit#gid=0)
Essentially, I'm looking through a messy tag field trying to pull out the important tag I need displayed in a separate cell. I want this done automatically so I don't have to keep pulling down my formula every morning to update the ticket sales pivot report.

A1: `fe220608-dcba-12p,mg220606-dcba,reg_confirm_sms_test,confirmation_sms_mc-guidebook,mailed_v2-guidebook,preview_reminder_call_1st_attempt,phase-preview-attendee,phase-preview-buyer,product_path_quickstart,product_workshop_registration,pb,me220624-dcba,pb_mg220606-dcba,pp_2023_pre_sale,pp-2023_guest-ticket_platinum,**pp-2023_ticket_platinum**,branding_package,branding_ob_form_finished,2022_webinar_test1_group,unsubscribed_mfcp-investor-related`
(I want to pull out that Platinum tag, and put it in a separate column)

Formula: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX({"pp-2023_ticket_general-seating","pp-2023_ticket_general-admission","pp-2023_ticket_silver","pp-2023_ticket_gold","pp-2023_ticket_platinum"},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"pp-2023_ticket_general-seating","pp-2023_ticket_general-admission","pp-2023_ticket_silver","pp-2023_ticket_gold","pp-2023_ticket_platinum"},A2)),0)),""))`

Expected Result:

`**pp-2023_ticket_platinum**`

Please let me know if there is an easier way to automate this.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(INDEX({
 "pp-2023_ticket_general-seating","pp-2023_ticket_general-admission",
 "pp-2023_ticket_silver","pp-2023_ticket_gold","pp-2023_ticket_platinum"},
 MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH({
 "pp-2023_ticket_general-seating","pp-2023_ticket_general-admission",
 "pp-2023_ticket_silver","pp-2023_ticket_gold","pp-2023_ticket_platinum"}, x)), ))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I really appreciate it! Makes me happy this morning. Any insight as to why it wasn't working? Always like to understand a little more about these array formulas.

Comment: @DerekWoodward culprit is TRUE in MATCH. for array you would need a column of trues  not just one